# How to create permanent Symbolic link in /tmp folder to start postgres?

Tags: linux, postgresql

I am running postgresql but with every system reboot, the symbolic link /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 gets deleted so I have to manually create it through

```
sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

and only then postgres start. Is there anyway I can automate this (say the command running at the time system starts) ? also why this /tmp link for postgres ? I am sure there is a better solution then to keep on creating the /tmp link after every reboot

I am on ubuntu 12.10 btw

EDIT - the code do look in reverse order but it is working now, see https://askubuntu.com/a/213462 too

Thanks

Comment: You appear to have the arguments reversed. I'd expect `ln -s /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 /tmp/`

Comment: I myself was surprised with this but if you see http://askubuntu.com/a/213462, the person said the other way worked for him! or is it that for this case, both ways can work ?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. Why do you need both? And I think wildplasser is right - that's linking from /tmp to /var/run/

Comment: @RichardHuxton - Rich, I don't need both, I was just telling what I saw in the link http://askubuntu.com/a/213462 and that how surprisingly it worked even though it looks in wrong order.

Comment: An alternative to would be to simply use a TCP based connection (through a port) instead of the unix socket. Then you don't need this at all.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Hi, can you tell me how to do it with TCP based connection ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to the [startup script](http://www.debianadmin.com/manage-linux-init-or-startup-scripts.html). You won't need sudo as all startup scripts are run as root. It should be located in `/etc/init.d`, so you can edit it with `sudo vim /etc/init.d/postgres`.